# How to increase volume of mediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am writing an app that in some situations warns user with an alarm sound. My problem is that in some situation volume of media playing may be decreased by user or even media volume is silent. I want to check the volume programatically and increase it to 100% and then play alarm.

Any idea? Note that I have tested `mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1)` and nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Alarm? because alarms will go off loud no matter the volume level is. Post your code plz

Comment: Not Android alarm! In fact a Police alarm sound!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't the function for setting the volume.
Here it's the setting of the volume to any value:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// For example to set the volume of played media to maximum.
audioManager.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
```

Comment: That's true. Also, if you want system dialog with volume to be shown, pass FLAG_SHOW_UI as a last param instead of 0.